# Reading a memory stream into byte array

Tags: .net, vb.net

I am having some trouble with reading a memory stream in chunks.

```
Dim ByteBuffer(4096) As Byte

While ProcessedBytes < FileLength

    BytesRead = MemoryStream.Read(ByteBuffer, 0, 4096)
    'Write the buffer to an output stream
    ProcessedBytes += BytesRead

End While
```

'MemoryStream.Read(ByteBuffer, 0, 4096)' is always returning zero. I have looked at 'MemoryStream.Length' and the stream definitely has some bytes in it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe it returns 0 because you reached the end of the stream. Make sure you set the position to 0 before starting reading your stream.

```
MemoryStream.Position = 0
```

or

```
MemoryStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin)
```

Answer (score 2):

If you're just trying to get the `byte[]` data out of the `MemoryStream`, you can call [MemoryStream.ToArray()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.memorystream.toarray.aspx):

```
Dim ByteBuffer() as Byte = MemoryStream.ToArray()
```

Otherwise, make sure to set your `MemoryStream`'s [Position](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.memorystream.position.aspx) to 0 prior to reading from it.